# VBA - Matching time in 2 different excel

Tags: time, matching

I would like to match workbook1 (A2) time to workbook2 (C4:C27) and return the value of row.

Workbook1
2:00 AM

Workbook2

12:00 AM
1:00 AM
2:00 AM
3:00 AM
4:00 AM
5:00 AM
6:00 AM
7:00 AM
8:00 AM
9:00 AM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
12:00 PM
1:00 PM
2:00 PM
3:00 PM
4:00 PM
5:00 PM
6:00 PM
7:00 PM
8:00 PM
9:00 PM
10:00 PM
11:00 PM

Below is my code

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()

Dim i As Integer
Dim intValueToFind As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim wbkSource As Workbook
Dim tm As Range
Dim ctm As String


Set tm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

mypath = "C:\Users\hlfoong\Desktop\Testing\"
fn = Dir(mypath & "pre*.xls")
Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(mypath & fn)
ctm = Format(tm, "h:mm AM/PM")

intValueToFind = ctm
'MsgBox ("time is " & ctm)

    For i = 4 To 27
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = intValueToFind Then
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")

End Sub
```

But it always return value not found. kindly help.